# thunderbird extension - iterate over messages in a folder

Tags: message, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm writing a thunderbird extension that should monitor one or more folders (from the left pane of the application) and if there are messages added to one of the monitored folders, they are sent automatically via webdav to a server (for archiving).

I found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Thunderbird/Account_examples) how to iterate over all folders in all accounts. My question is how can I iterate over the messages (mails) in a folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [nsiMsgFolder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIMsgFolder) interface should provide everything you need. If you want to react on incoming messages, I'd register a [nsiFolderListener](http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/mailnews/base/public/nsIFolderListener.idl). It gets notified everytime a message is added to the folder.

You could check if [these snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/HowTos/Common_Thunderbird_Use_Cases/Open_Folder#List_Messages) help you.

I also found a somewhat older document detailing the [mail event system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Thunderbird/Mail_event_system). It is flagged as in need of technical review but might give you a decent starting point.